# Python - Dynamically change number of arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I want to calculate a cartesian product from a changing number of sets.

The cartesian product can be computed using `itertools.product(*args, repeat=1)`

```
itertools.product(set1, set2, repeat=1)
```

but the number of sets is actually unknown, it depends on the data. Sometimes it might be 2 groups, sometimes 3 or more.

Is there a way to submit *args such that it can dynamically change the number of arguments?

```
myargs = [set1, set2, set3]
itertools.product(myargs,repeat=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is such a way. Use the `*` argument expansion operator:

```
myargs = [set1, set2, set3]
itertools.product(*myargs,repeat=1)
```

Reference:

- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls